# How to get rid of the black virtual home button on iphone 10, 11

Tags: swift, iphone

Hi is there a way to get rid of the "black line" (virtual home button) on iphone 10, 11... by code OR at least display this bar on the right (my app is displayed on landscape mode) Txs ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

According to [prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887510-prefershomeindicatorautohidden)

Set your return value as required.

> true if your view controller lets the system determine when to hide
>   the indicator, or false if you want the indicator shown at all times.
>   The default implementation of this method returns false.

Comment: Is it all about points? "You are welcome" would have been nice :) @chirag90